# windows batch nested for loops and variables

Tags: loops, batch-file, iteration

I've been writing a batch script to catalog ~7tb worth of ripped media that I have stored on my pc. While the majority of the script works, I've been stuck on the portion that automatically determines whether a folder contains a TV show or Movie. This function works by assigning a weighted value to each category (movie vs tv) by taking the root folder's name (eg. Die_Hard), processing the names of any subfolders that may exist within, and spits out a value that the main program then converts into a T for tv or M for movie, along with a confidence score. The problem I'm having is that the function can't parse through the keywords correctly, and is marking TV shows as movies and vice versa. If I do the calculations by hand it works out fine, but I generally write scripts for Bash and I don't really understand what's not working here.

```bash
:DETERMINE
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    REM DT NAME
    set "DTNM=%~1"
    echo %DTNM%
    REM DT Location
    set "DLOC=%~2"
    REM echo %DLOC%
    REM DT Score
    set /A dtq=0
    REM DT Movie Weight
    set /A DTMV=0
    REM DT TV Weight
    set /A DTTV=0
    REM DT TV Keywords
    set "DTTR=Season,90;Volume,70;TV,45;S1,100;V1,75;"
    REM DT Movie Keywords
    set "DMVT=%DTNM%,45;Theatrical,90;Extended,60;Unrated,60;Extra,5;Bonus,10;Bonus-Content,15;Bonus-Disc,12;Bonus-Disk,12;Bonus_Content,15;Bonus_Disc,12;Bonus_Disk,12;Bonus Content,15;Bonus Disc,12;Bonus Disk,12;Special,2;Special-Features,18;Special-Content,15;Special_Features,18;Special_Content,15;Special Features,18;Special Content,15;"
    REM DMTV Calculator
    REM Iterate through subfolders
    for /f "tokens=*" %%U in ('dir /b /ad "%DLOC%"') do (
        REM Iterate through Keyword list
        for /f "tokens=* delims=;" %%V in ("%DMVT%") do (
            REM Split Keyword from weight
            REM echo %%V
            for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=," %%W in ("%%V") do (
                echo %%U|find /I "%%X" >nul
                if errorlevel 0 ( @set /A DMTV=!DMTV! + %%X )
                REM echo %%U %%W %%X
            echo 1
            )
        )
        REM DMTV escapw workaround
        set DMTV=!DMTV!
    )
    REM DTTV Calculator
    REM Iterate through subfolders
    for /f "tokens=*" %%T in ('dir /b /ad "%DLOC%"') do (
        REM Iterate through keyword list
        for /f "tokens=* delims=;" %%S in ("%DTTR%") do (
            REM split keyword from weight
            for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=," %%Q in ("%%S") do (
                echo %%T|find /I "%%R" >nul
                REM echo %%T %%Q %%R
                if errorlevel 0 ( @set /A DTTV=!DTTV! + %%R )
            )
        )
        REM DMTV escapw workaround
        set DTTV=!DTTV!
    )
    echo %DMTV% %DTTV%
    
    set /A DEQ=%DMTV% - %DTTV%
    echo %DEQ%
    ENDLOCAL
    GOTO:EOF
```

For reference, the subfolders for TV shows would be the season/volume numbers, (eg. S1, S2), while movies are located directly under the root folder, with the exception of series and trilogies where the subfolders share the same name as the root folder but have numbers indicating the movie as well.

The script should output a positive number for Movies and negative for TV shows. The farther the number is from 0 the greater the confidence score. I have a version of the script that uses 20+ layers nested If statements, but that is impossible to add new keywords to and sometimes outputs incorrect numbers. I've tried parsing the keywords different ways, and even using two strings, one for the keywords and one for the accompanying ratings. If this was bash I could use arrays, but afaik that's not possible here.

The output from this function should look like this:
`45` (for a movie or series of movies) or `-100` for a tv show.

Once the main program parses the output, it would look like this:

```
Discs
   Airplane - 2 Movies - 100% (90) [1080/XX GB]
   ...
   JOHN WICK - 4 Movies - 100% (180) [UHD/XX GB]
   ...
   The Office - 9 Seasons - 100% (-900) [NTSC/XX GB]
   ...
```

But currently, the subroutine output looks like this:

Shell window:

```
...
Airplane
Missing operator.
1
Missing operator.
1
Missing operator.
Missing operator.
90 180
-90
...
```

Main Program Output:

```
   Airplane - 90 Seasons - 90% (-90) [1080/XX GB]
```

Comment: One item that jumps out immediately is `if errorlevel 0` which means `always`. `IF ERRORLEVEL n` is TRUE if the runtime (ie. current) `errorlevel` is n **or greater than n**. It would be helpful to provide a listing of the relevant full filenames of the target files producing the results you've described. `dir /s /b "airplane" "john wick" "the office"` should generate such a list.

Comment: In essence, replace `if errorlevel 0` with `If Not ErrorLevel 1`. I would probably change `set /A DMTV=!DMTV! + %%X` and `set /A DTTV=!DTTV! + %%R` to `Set /A DMTV += %%X` and `Set /A DTTV += %%R` too. Then I'd change `set /A DEQ=%DMTV% - %DTTV%` to `Set /A DEQ=DMTV - DTTV`.

Comment: @Magoo the script should only be searching the first level of folders under the root folder. ```Airplane: Airplane, Airplane_II  John_Wick: Chapter 1, Chapter 2, Parabellum, Chapter 4  The_Office: Seasons 1-9```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a break from this for a while... but I figured it out.
It now outputs the correct weights for each category.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
REM DT NAME
set "DTNM=%~1"
REM DT Location
set "DLOC=%~2"
set DDBG=0
if %DDBG% EQU 1 ( echo # ---%DTNM% & echo # %DLOC%)
REM DT Score
set /A dtq=0
REM DT Movie Weight
set /A DTMV=10
REM DT TV Weight
set /A DTTV=0
REM DT TV Keywords
set "DTTR=Season,90;Volume,70;TV,45;^S[0123456789][0123456789],100;^S[0123456789],100;^V[0123456789][0123456789],75;"
REM DT Movie Keywords
set "DMVT=%DTNM%,45;^[0123456789],10;Theatrical,90;Extended,60;Unrated,60;Extra,5;Bonus,10;Bonus-Content,15;Bonus-Disc,12;Bonus-Disk,12;Bonus_Content,15;Bonus_Disc,12;Bonus_Disk,12;Bonus Content,15;Bonus Disc,12;Bonus Disk,12;Special,2;Special-Features,18;Special-Content,15;Special_Features,18;Special_Content,15;Special Features,18;Special Content,15;"
set DMTC=0
set DMMC=0
REM DMTV Calculator
REM Iterate through subfolders
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%U in ('dir /b /ad "%DLOC%"') do (
    REM Iterate through Keyword list
    for %%V in ("%DMVT:;=" "%") do (
        REM Split Keyword from weight
        REM echo %%V
        for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=," %%W in (%%V) do (
            REM echo %%U
            REM echo | set /p= is equivalent to echo -n
            if %DDBG% EQU 1 (echo | set /p=# "TITLE" %%U "TOKEN" %%W "WEIGHT" %%X)
            echo %%U|findstr /R /I /M "%%W" >nul
            if !errorlevel!==0 ( @set /A DMTV=!DMTV! + %%X & if %DDBG% EQU 1 (echo  "Match")) else (if %DDBG% EQU 1 (echo  "No Match"))
            REM echo %%U %%W %%X
        REM echo 1
        set /A DMMC+=1
        )
    )
REM DMTV escapw workaround
set DMTV=!DMTV!
)
REM DTTV Calculator
REM Iterate through subfolders
for /f "tokens=*" %%U in ('dir /b /ad "%DLOC%"') do (
    REM Iterate through keyword list
    for %%V in ("%DTTR:;=" "%") do (
        REM split keyword from weight
        for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=," %%W in (%%V) do (
            REM echo | set /p= is equivalent to echo -n
            if %DDBG% EQU 1 (echo | set /p=# "TITLE" %%U "TOKEN" %%W "WEIGHT" %%X)
            echo %%U|findstr /R /I /M "%%W" >nul
            REM echo %%T %%Q %%R
            if !errorlevel!==0 ( @set /A DTTV=!DTTV! + %%X & if %DDBG% EQU 1 (echo  "Match")) else (if %DDBG% EQU 1 (echo  "No Match"))
        set /A DMTC+=1
        )
    )
REM DMTV escapw workaround
set DTTV=!DTTV!
)
REM empty movie score workaround (adds one to movie in case score is null or 0)
set /A DMTV+=1
if %DDBG% EQU 1 (echo # "MOV ITR" !DMMC! "TV ITR" !DMTC! "MOV SCR" %DMTV% "TV SCR" -%DTTV%)

set /A DEQ=%DMTV% - %DTTV%
if %DDBG% EQU 1 (echo %DEQ%)
set U=
ENDLOCAL & set "DEQ=%DEQ%"
GOTO:EOF
```

Here's a summary of what I fixed:

- I replaced `Find` with `FindStr`. By using `FindStr` I gained the ability to use regex. This allowed the detection of numbers in folder names.
- `FindStr` outputs 3 error conditions. `0` means success, `1` means no match, and `2` means failure. This means that `if errorlevel 0` is the correct usage in this scenario. Also, `if errorlevel 0` is equivalent to `if !errorlevel!==0` when `DelayedExpansion` is enabled.
- Both calculation sections now use the same variables. I originally thought this would cause problems, but using different variables actually caused more when there were large amounts of tokens generated by `for` statements.
- I had to use a standard `for` loop in the case of `for %%V in ("%DTTR:;=" "%")` as it was *not* looping through a directory and I did not want each token getting it's own variable. I needed it to parse one token at a time and only use one variable, in this case `%%V`.
- I was using `%%X` instead of `%%W` in `FindStr`. This meant it was searching for the weight and not the keyword.
- I added a debug mode so I could disable the print output, since this is a subroutine and the final program won't need output from this section.
- I added 1 to `DMTV` (the final value of the movie calculation) as when there are no folders in the specified directory `DMTV` is cleared.

Comment: `if errorlevel 0 is equivalent to if !errorlevel!==0` - no, it isn't. It's equivalent to `if !errorlevel! geq 0`